# Openlayer: remove multiple popups

Tags: php, javascript, html, openlayers

I am trying to create a spatial survey using OpenLayers 2.11, but have some issues with a function for closing multiple popups.

The following code works fine for one popup, but the function fails to both close multiple popups and post the content.

Is there an OpenLayers method to destroy old popups when creating a new popup?

```
function submitform() {
  document.myform.submit();
  loop_popups();
}
```

--

```
function loop_popups() {
  for( var i = 0; i < map.popups.length; ++i ) { 
    map.removePopup(map.popups[i]); 
  };
}
```

--

```
<form name="myform" action="sqlinsert.php" method="post" target="_blank">
<a href="javascript: submitform()">Save/close</a>
```

Comment: Doesn't form.submit() cause page reload?

Answer (score 6):

Using `i` to count through the array while removing members from it only removes half the markers. Instead, try:

```
while( map.popups.length ) {
  map.removePopup( map.popups[0] );
}
```

If you want to make absolutely sure the loop doesn't repeat forever:

```
/**
 * Closes all the popups.
 */
function closePopups() {
  // Make sure the loop terminates...
  var maxIterations = 100;

  while( map.popups.length && --maxIterations ) {
    var popup = map.popups[0];
    map.removePopup( popup );
    popup.destroy();
  }
}
```

This type of constrained looping technique is used in Nuclear Power Plants.

Assume you have 5 popups.

1. popups = 5, i = 0, max.popups.length = 5
2. popups = 4, i = 1, max.popups.length = 4
3. popups = 3, i = 2, max.popups.length = 3
4. popups = 2, i = 3, max.popups.length = 2

The value of `i` now exceeds `max.popups.length`. The loop terminates, but some popups have not been closed. (There may have even been an index out of bounds error when trying to access the popups array...)

You could have written your loop as:

```
function loop_popups() {
  for( var i = map.popups.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) { 
    map.removePopup(map.popups[i]); 
  };
}
```

This no longer compares against a moving target, and will also execute faster than your original loop because comparing to zero is faster than comparing against a register (on most computer architectures).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `exclusive: true` to `addPopup` to automatically close all other popups, as in:

```
map.addPopup(popup, true)
```

See http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.addPopup

I've found this useful in dealing with the buggy-ass nature of OpenLayers itself. I'm not sure what the other user was trying to do in making the comparison with nuclear power plants; that was completely unnecessary.